# How to get data from json in order to save them in database?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, knockout.js

I am beginner in Javascript/jQuery and I am working on an interface made with KnockoutJS, so I have several models. I would like to save all the data in the database but I don't know how to do it.

I started with :

```
   self.save = function() {
        var data = ko.toJS(self);
        var test = ko.toJSON(self);
        console.log(test);
    }

   $.ajax({
       url: "myURL",
       data: {'carrier': data.carrier},
       type: "POST",
   });
```

and this is the result of the console.log :

```
   {"id":1,"carrier":"1","Settings":[{"id":1,"price":{"id":1,"DeliveryStandard":"3.00","DeliveryExpress":"6.00","Details":{"id":1,"Standard":[{"id":1,"fromPrice":0,"maxPrice":"45.000"}],"Express"[{"id":1,"fromPrice":0,"maxPrice":"66.000"}]}}}}]}
```

I can get the value of carrier by using data.carrier but I don't know how to get the other data like DeiveryStandard, DeliveryExpress, fromPrice, maxPrice ...

Have you got an idea?

Thanks you in advance, and sorry if my question is silly!

Comment: Why not send the entire content of the test variable to the server?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! In fact "myURL"  is a webservice that corresponds to the table which contains "carrier" and I would like to send each data in the webservice corresponding but I don't know if it is possible..

Comment: So you have other webservices for the other pieces of the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
console.log(data.Settings[0].price.DeliveryStandard);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you format your JSON into a more readable format, with indenting, it makes it a lot easier to understand:

(though it should be noted that it is only technically JSON while in a string format, outside of that it is just a standard javascript object)

```
{
"id":1,
"carrier":"1",
"Settings":[
    {
    "id":1,
    "price": { "id":1,
               "DeliveryStandard":"3.00",
               "DeliveryExpress":"6.00",
               "Details": { "id":1,
                            "Standard": [{"id":1,
                                          "fromPrice":0,
                                          "maxPrice":"45.000"
                                          }],
                            "Express" //Missing semi-colon
                                     [{"id":1,
                                        "fromPrice":0,
                                        "maxPrice":"66.000"
                                      }]
                          }
             }
   }}//One too many closing braces
   ]
}
```

First thing to note is you have 2 syntax errors, highlighted above with comments. So fix them first! (Though I wonder if they are typos as you seem to have it working at your end)

---

Then we can look at the structure tree to work out where the values you want are...

`DeiveryStandard` and `DeliveryExpress` are both properties of an object assigned to `price`, which it a property of the first item in the `Settings` array. So you can access them like so:

```
var DeliveryStandard = data.Settings[0].price.DeliveryStandard;
var DeliveryExpress= data.Settings[0].price.DeliveryExpress;
```

`fromPrice` and `maxPrice` are found multiple times, in both `Standard` and `Express` items. So you need to decide what version you need. If you want `Standard` then you can get the first item of the `Standard` array like so:

```
var standardObject = data.Settings[0].price.Details.Standard[0];
```

Which you can then access the properties of like:

```
var fromPrice = standardObject.fromPrice;
var maxPrice = standardObject.maxPrice;
```

I am sure you can work out how to get the `Express` version of the same data!

---

From what you seem to have been able to work out on your own, I think your problem is not knowing how to deal with the arrays. Note that arrays are defined with square brackets `[]`, and elements within an array should be accessed with a zero-based index, for example: `array[0]` for the first element, and `array[1]` for the second element.

Answer (score 0):

*Fixed some errors in your JSON*.

```
var j = {
    "id" : 1,
    "carrier" : "1",
    "Settings" : [{
            "id" : 1,
            "price" : {
                "id" : 1,
                "DeliveryStandard" : "3.00",
                "DeliveryExpress" : "6.00",
                "Details" : {
                    "id" : 1,
                    "Standard" : [
                        {
                            "id" : 1,
                            "fromPrice" : 0,
                            "maxPrice" : "45.000"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Express": [
                        {
                            "id" : 1,
                            "fromPrice" : 0,
                            "maxPrice" : "66.000"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
};

alert(j.Settings[0].price.DeliveryStandard);
alert(j.Settings[0].price.DeliveryExpress);
alert(j.Settings[0].price.Details.Standard[0].fromPrice);
alert(j.Settings[0].price.Details.Standard[0].maxPrice);
```